# Mongooseim rosters webhook backend

Tags: xmpp, mongoose-im

I am planning to build a communication system based on mongooseim platform. I still want to use common user group across all the applications. What is the best stratergy of avoiding data duplication and maintaining rosters backend outside the mongooseim database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently MongooseIM supports 3 backend types to store roster:

- RDBMS (MySQL, Postgres, MSSQL)
- Riak
- Mnesia (internal Erlang database)

If you want to integrate roster with your other web service without data duplication, you need to implement new backed talking to your service directly.

A generic backend is a good idea, I'll discuss this with the team and probably we add it to our backlog. I'm not able to promise any dates when this would be implemented, though.

Comment: Thank you, is there any documentation to be followed